# What is the latest advice for using tex and providing a Word as output?

Tags: document-classes, latex-to-word

Despite many "older answers" I should like the latest advice. I love tex, and I use TeXstudio. Due to collaborators needing Word- I would like to know best way to convert or get an output in Word.

Comment: TeX4ht is one of a better converter ...

Comment: Best solution would be to  agree on one common tool. Converters are far from perfect.

Comment: Do they really need Word or just Not-LaTeX? You could use Markdown for them and then try the markdown package to get it into LaTeX...